# TypeError when rounding up float values of a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding, typeerror

Given a numpy array consisting of float values, e.g.:

```
floatvalues = [1.3423 , 40.331 , 3.123894,
               93.3941, 1.34, 23.59]
```

The numpy array I use has 8000 columns and 38 rows. My goal was to determine the maximum of each row and return those maximum values as a vector. Therefore I created a dataframe of the np.array and used the maximum  function. After that, I wanted to round up the maximum values to a distinct amount of decimals (e.g. decimals=3). Desired result:

```
0   93.395 
1   40.332 
2   23.590
```

Therefore I used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

def roundup(value, decimals=0):
    n = 10**-decimals
    return round(math.ceil(value / n) * n, decimals)

input_file = np.load("U:\\floatvalues.npy")
input_array = pd.DataFrame(input_file)
inputs_max = np.max(input_array, axis=0)

rounded_inputs_max = roundup(inputs_max, 4)
print(rounded_inputs_max)
```

This led to:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

So I tried to directly access the maximum values of the np.array and not the ones out of the DataFrame:

```
 input_file = np.load("U:\\floatvalues.npy)
 #input_array = pd.DataFrame(input_file)
 inputs_max = np.max(input_file, axis=0)

 rounded_inputs_max = roundup(inputs_max,4)
 print(rounded_inputs_max)
```

This led to:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Preferably, I would like the first way to work out using the DataFrame. Can somebody help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use `np.round(inputs_max, 3)` as opposed to the custom function you use?

Comment: try `inputs_max = np.max(np.asarray(input_array), axis=0)`

Comment: I can't use the round function, because I always want to round up to a certain decimal. That's why I'm using the custom one. e.g.: 1,40302 to 4th decimal: 1,4031. @Vaibhavgusain : using your suggestion: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: can you pls tell the line where the error occur ?

Comment: Line 7 (return) and Line 13 (where function is called, rounded_inputs_max=...)

Comment: You need to vectorise your roundup function.  It works on a scalar but doesn't work on a numpy array.

Comment: @TlsChris and how does that work?

Comment: Jesus christ... after having edited 10** to 10.0** and vectorizing the function, everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't tested,especially for where the arr[n] is at the correct rounding.

```
In [10]: def np_roundup(arr,pl):
    ...:     factor=10**pl
    ...:     temp=arr*factor
    ...:     t_int=temp.astype(np.int32)
    ...:     rem=(temp-t_int)>0
    ...:     t_int+=rem
    ...:     return t_int/factor
```

There may be neater numpy functions.

Edit 18th Dec
There is a numpy ceil function I've only just noticed.

```
def np_roundup(arr, pl):
    factor=10**pl
    return np.ceil(arr*factor)/factor
```

a lot neater.

HTH